# Pandas ValueError: 'x' is neither a valid single color nor a color sequence consisting of single character color specifiers such as 'rgb'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm running the following code and plotting a graph using plot() in a jupyter notebook.

```
xg = list(df_composite['xG_geral'].values)
g = list(df_composite['Goal_geral'].values)
index = list(df_composite['clube'].values)

df = pd.DataFrame({'xG': xg,
                    'G': g}, index=index)
ax = df.plot.bar(rot=90, color={"xG": "orange", "G": "green"},figsize=(25,15))
```

The above works like a charm and plots the colored graph.

---

However, if I run the exact same snippet as python script within an application, it breaks with the following error:

```
ValueError: 'xG' is neither a valid single color nor a color sequence consisting of single character color specifiers such as 'rgb'. Note also that the latter is deprecated.
```

I don't know whether this is related to the graph being exported, if I must avoid its being shown or else, given the fact that I only need to save it and not show it.

I've found this issue in matplotlib [matplotlib issue](https://github.com/ewels/MultiQC/issues/1263), but it did not help me.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: As the Jupyter working and [the current documentation indicate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html), that should be valid code. I suspect you aren't using the same versions of Pandas in the two locations? What happens if you run that script you are trying run from inside the notebook using `%run <script_name_here>.py`. You'll probably need to put a copy of the script alongside the notebook for that to work.